# Долгое взаимодействие с базой данных. Уместное создание ApplicationContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

В базу данных помещена информация об учебных аудиториях, кафедрах, типах занятий, преподавателях и дисциплинах. Программа в дальнейшем использует эти заранее заданные элементы. 
На начальных этапах вся эта информация считывалась из кода (в коде создавались экземпляры соответствующих классов), я немного переделал это дело под Entity Framework, и все стало происходить на недопустимо большое количество времени дольше. То, что делалось за несколько секунд, теперь выполняется три минуты. Наверное, это происходит из-за того, что в каждом методе отдельно используется данная конструкция:

```
using(ApplicationContex db = new ApplicationContext()) {}
```

Может нужно ее использовать один раз в Main, а потом передавать как входной параметр? В общем, вопрос в том, как оптимально подключаться к базе данных, чтобы выполнение программы не растягивалось на несколько минут вместо секунд.

UPD:
Методом тыка обнаружил, что происходит это из-за

```
Database.EnsureCreated();
```

Другое дело, как сделать по-другому. Ведь изначально база данных создается из программы, просто в последующих запусках ее уже не нужно создавать.

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<> Buildings { get; set; }
        и др сеты

        public ApplicationContext()
        {
            //Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=ScheduleProblemeDB;Username=postgres;Password=12345");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            конфигурации
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Наверное, это происходит из-за того..` откуда такая инфа? Если у вас что то тормозит, то надо профилировать и смотреть узкие места, а не гадать. Само по себе создание контекста еще ничего не значит, соединение к БД все равно берется из пула. Смотрите профайлером, смотрите запросы между приложением и сервером БД, и когда найдете причину тормозов, тогда и думайте, что с ней делать.

Comment: Нет. При создании соединения используется пулл подключений. Другими словами проблема с быстродействием Вашего кода находится не здесь. Одна из распостранённых ошибок при начале использования EF - это излишняя материализация сущностей. Проверьте исполняемые запросы к БД в профайлере MS SQL Management Studio и это сразу покажет Вам проблемные места.

Comment: Вопрос задан в отрыве от каких-то конкретных и измеримых вещей. Не приведено ни одной строчки кода, ни одного запроса... о чём можно предметно говорить в таком вопросе? Ни о чём - только дать совет "возьмите профилировщик в руки", спросить "есть ли индексы" и "используется ли lazy loading". Проголосовал за закрытие.

Comment: Я осознал, что это из-за Database.EnsureCreated(). Но как тогда иначе контролировать существование и нормальность базы данных?

Comment: а вы это на каждый чих запускаете что ли? Оно дожно быть запущено 1 раз на старте и всё

Comment: @tym32167 в конструкторе ApplicationContext было.

Comment: оно там не нужно, в конструкторе

Comment: @tym32167 понял, принял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выяснилось, это происходило из-за вызова метода Database.EnsureCreated() внутри конструктора ApplicationContext().
Вместо этого лучше, видимо, вызывать этот метод из Main():

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {                
            using(ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
            {
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }
         }
     }
```