# Login failed при попытке получить данные из БД в ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Согласно [этому](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/3.2.php) руководству, пытаюсь создать и инициализировать базу данных. Насколько я понимаю, при использовании EntityFramework в ASP.NET Core, БД должна создаваться сама при запуске приложения. Однако при попытке обратиться к базе выкидывается исключение:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. SqlException: Cannot open database "devicesdbstore" requested by the
>   login. The login failed. Login failed for user

Подключаюсь к базе так:

```
string con = "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=devicesdbstore;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
services.AddDbContext<Device_info_context>(options => options.UseSqlServer(con));
```

Если для ответа на вопрос необходима ещё какая-то информация, пишите в комментарии, всё предоставлю.

Comment: база должна быть создана https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db?tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @Konst Готов спорить, потому что уже решил вопрос. Она точно создаётся автоматически.

Answer (score 1):

```
public DbSet<Device_info> Devices { get; set; }
        public Device_info_context(DbContextOptions<Device_info_context> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated(); // Эту строку было необходимо добавить в конструктор чтобы проблема решилась! 
        }
```

Comment: отлично, о чём я и писал, она у вас отсутствовала

Comment: @Konst Но я ведь не создавал её вручную через клиент MS SQLServer

Comment: Эту строчку наверное надо выполнять при запуске приложения один раз, а не каждый раз при создании контекста

Comment: @tym32167 Эта функция как раз и сделана так, что выполняется только один раз и в том случае, если базы данных нет. По сути, она проверяет, есть ли база, и если нет, создаёт её. (Это написано в описании в IDE)

Comment: ну и в вашем случае она будет проверять создана база или нет при каждом создании контекста, что сильно ударит по производительности. Потому и говорю, запускайте строчку один раз при старте приложения, не запускайте её на каждое создание контекста

Comment: В общем, с вашим подходом будет 2 проблемы: [проблема с производительностью](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/983693/179763), [Вы не сможете использовать миграции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/908760/179763)